# Multiply two vectors element by element

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

I want to multiply these two vectors, but I cannot
It does not sum the result:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([[0.2], 
              [0.2],
              [0.2]])
t = [0]
for i in range(0, 2):
    for j in range(0, 2):
        t = sum(x[i] * y[j])
        print(t)
    print(t)
```

Output:

```py
0.2
0.2
0.4
0.4
```

[original code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O27GG.png)

Comment: Please type out your code using the formatting tools in the editor. Images of code are not acceptable.

Comment: Doing `t=...` inside the loop does not accumulate anything outside it.  It's not a good idea to use `numpy` without first learning the basics of Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a homework problem?
Your biggest problem is that `for i in range(0, 2):` only loops through `i = 0, 1`, not `i = 0, 1, 2` as you intend.

Comment: Updated to say *homework. Otherwise I would just use numpy